# Extract node value from xml resembling string C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am having strings like below

```
<ad nameId="\862094\"></ad>
```

or comma seprated like below

```
<ad nameId="\862593\"></ad>,<ad nameId="\862094\"></ad>,<ad nameId="\865599\"></ad>
```

How to extract nameId value and store in single string like below

```
string extractedValues ="862094";
```

or in case of comma seprated string above

```
string extractedMultipleValues ="862593,862094,865599";
```

This is what I have started trying with but not sure

```
string myString = "<ad nameId="\862593\"></ad>,<ad nameId="\862094\"></ad>,<ad         
                    nameId="\865599\"></ad>";
string[] myStringArray = myString .Split(',');
foreach (string str in myStringArray )
{

   xd.LoadXml(str);
   chkStringVal = xd.SelectSingleNode("/ad/@nameId").Value;
}
```

Comment: am wondering why that input is not in pure `xml`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see code below to extract all numbers in your example:

```
   string value = @"<ad nameId=""\862093\""></ad>,<ad nameId=""\862094\""></ad>,<ad nameId=""\865599\""></ad>";
   var matches = Regex.Matches(value, @"(\\\d*\\)", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
   foreach (Group item in matches)
   {
     string yourMatchNumber = item.Value;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Search for:

```
<ad nameId="\\(\d*)\\"><\/ad>
```

Replace with:

```
$1
```

Note that you must search globally. Example: http://www.regex101.com/r/pL2lX1

Comment: @mhasan Sorry, I am not proficient in C# so I would probably mess it up. Simply apply the logic from the above regex in your program and it should work. If you don't know how to work with regexes in C#, I suggest Google.

Comment: Thanks a lot..much appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Try like this;

```
string s = @"<ad nameId=""\862094\""></ad>";
if (!(s.Contains(",")))
{

    string extractedValues = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("\\") + 1, s.LastIndexOf("\\") - s.IndexOf("\\") - 1);
}
else
{
    string[] array = s.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    string extractedMultipleValues = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
         extractedMultipleValues += array[i].Substring(array[i].IndexOf("\\") + 1, array[i].LastIndexOf("\\") - array[i].IndexOf("\\") - 1) + ",";
    }

    Console.WriteLine(extractedMultipleValues.Substring(0, extractedMultipleValues.Length -1));
}
```

Comment: the number of comma seprated string is not fixed ..can be two , 3 or more

Comment: `Length cannaot be less than zero` exception thrown at  `extractedMultipleValues = array[i].Substring(array[i].IndexOf("\\") + 1, array[i].LastIndexOf("\\") - array[i].IndexOf("\\") - 1) + @",";`

Answer (score 1):

mhasan, here goes an example of what you need(well almost)

**EDITED**: complete code (it's a little tricky)

[image]

(Sorry for the image but i have some troubles with tags in the editor, i can send the code by email if you want :) )

A little explanation about the code, it replaces all ocurrences of parsePattern in the given string, so if the given string has multiple tags separated by "," the final result will be the numbers separated by "," stored in parse variable....

Hope it helps